# How to force two or more tikzpictures to be below each other in standalone class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

### Original message

I want to force two or more `tikzpictures` to be below each other in the `standalone` class. I am not sure how to do this. Here is the minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,
  ]        
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% line break here!

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,    
  ]   
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

---

### Update

The result should look like this. Both tikzpictures should be on the same PDF page. 
[image]

Comment: I assume you meant one above the other, hence my edit.

Comment: No, I meant "below" each other.

Comment: Well, the first above the second, or the second below the first, that's the same thing really. But we can agree that "among" was wrong, at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so, one page but one chart on top of the other? (Simply add `varwidth` class option, as suggested by Torbjørn.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

%\vbox{% <-- redundant, thanks to `varwidth' class option
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,
  ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,
  ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}

\end{document}
```

Or, on separate pages?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,
  ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,
  ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative to the `\vbox`: add `varwidth` as a class option.

Comment: I made an update for the question.

Comment: @Ben Doesn't the first code box already do what you want?

Comment: Yes, I know. I just want to let you (and future readers) know, what I was exactly looking for.

Comment: The `varwidth` option is even easier to be used than `\vbox` (Thanks to @TorbjørnT) .

Comment: If the two plots were different, how could you align them vertically at `y-axis`?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,
  ]        
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\\

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=12cm,
    height=3cm,    
  ]   
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]